# Roblox Studio: Print text, when leaderboard kill value reaches 10

Tags: printing, leaderboard, roblox

Is there a way in Roblox Studio, when a leaderboard kill value reaches 10 print or do anything. (leaderstats model already exists at game.Players.(player))

Answer (score 0):

Say the variable stats is the model in the workspace for the player stats with the relevant player as its parent:

```
if stats.KO == 10 then
    print("A player just hit 10 kills!")
end
```

Pay attention to the console. Try printing the player's name to check to make sure that you actually have the player as a variable, like this.

```
print(player.Name)
```

That will confirm that you actually referenced the player correctly.